# Audio Session plugin could not be found

Tags: flutter, kotlin, avaudiosessioncategory

I tried to exclude the audio session from the build directory.

I would like to disable audio session, I believe that is for ios, and I don't need ios at this time.
I'm building a android.

With the gradle below should I delete the java reference?
I only need kotlin based app

```
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01
    C:\tools\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\audio_session-    0.0.11\android\src\main\java\com\ryanheise\audio_session\AndroidAudioManager.java:11: error: package io.flutter.plugin.common does not exist
import io.flutter.plugin.common.BinaryMessenger;
`your text`                               ^
   C:\tools\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\audio_session-0.0.11\android\src\main\java\com\ryanheise\audio_session\AndroidAudioManager.java:12: error: package io.flutter.plugin.common does not exist
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodCall;
                               ^
  C:\tools\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\audio_session-0.0.11\android\src\main\java\com\ryanheise\audio_session\AndroidAudioManager.java:13: error: package io.flutter.plugin.common does not exist
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel;
```

App/build gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
compileSdkVersion 33

compileOptions {
sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}

kotlinOptions {
       jvmTarget = '1.8'
}

 sourceSets {
 main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
```